Дебагинг RTK Query функции updatequerydata
Мне необходимо обновить данные в state сразу после отправки на сервер чтобы небыло задержки, однако у меня ничего не просиходит.
Я хочу посмотреть что находится в переменных draft" и "diaryEntry" однако console.log() не работает внутри updateQueryData. только если внутри onQueryStarted.  console.log(current()) так же не дает никаких результатов а попытка внутри  onQueryStarted вызвать getState().getAllDiaryEntries дает undefined.
updateDiaryEntry: builder.mutation({
            query: ({ id, data }) => ({
                url: `diaryEntries/${id}`,
                method: 'PUT',
                body: data,
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['DiaryEntry'],
            async onQueryStarted({ id, data }, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
                console.log(data);

                const patchResult = dispatch(
                    api.util.updateQueryData('getAllDiaryEntries', data, (draft: any) => {
                        const diaryEntry = draft.find((entry) => entry._id === id);

                        Object.assign(diaryEntry, data);
                    })
                );
                try {
                    await queryFulfilled;
                } catch {
                    patchResult.undo();
                }
            },
        }),

